# Radio Button choice to prefill specific text to Textarea to then be parsed to server

Tags: function, variables, radio-button, textarea

The long and short of what I need to be able to do is to have HTML that consists of five or more radiobuttons. Based on the radiobutton choice, a freeform textarea will then be filled with text of my choosing to then later be parsed and sent to the server.

I am able to create the radiobuttons, the text area, and have the parse code. I'm having trouble prefilling my text to the textarea based on the radiobutton choice.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in the body tag of the document:

```
<textarea id="txt"></textarea><br />
<script>
txt=document.getElementById("txt");
</script>
<input type="radio" onclick="txt.value='value1'">
<input type="radio" onclick="txt.value='value2'">
<input type="radio" onclick="txt.value='value3'">
<input type="radio" onclick="txt.value='value4'">
<input type="radio" onclick="txt.value='value5'">
```